# In Java how do I change the length of a ArrayBlockedQueue?

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I'm creating a media player app for Android.  I have two threads: one producing audio frames, and another consuming those frames.

I want my customer to be able to experiment with using different sizes of ArrayBlockedQueue's, from "no" buffering (really 1) to up to 10 blocks of buffering.

I can't seem to find any classes in Java that provide a similar functionality to ArrayBlockedQueue, but allows me to dynamically make the list of items longer/shorter.

Question 1) Does anyone know of a class that functions similar to ArrayBlockedQueue, yet allows me to change the amount of items to hold?

Then I had a strange thought: Could I fudge it?  Could I create a new ArrayBlockedQueue with the new size, and step through copying the 1-10 items that are currently in the old ArrayBlockedQueue and putting them into the new ArrayBlockedQueue, and then storing a pointer to the new ArrayBlockedQueue over the old one?

Since there'll never be more than 10 (or whatever my buffer limit is), it shouldn't take too much time copying the items to the new array.

Question 2) Is that a "reasonable" way to approach an ArrayBlockedQueue implementation that still gives me flexibility?

Question 3)Is there a better way to approach this?

-Ken

Comment: could you not look up the [`remainingCapacity()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity--) and add based on it?

Comment: I'm using the blocking capacity of the queue as the thing that coordinates the input and output of my two threads.  I would very much like to keep any pending put() or take() calls hanging as appropriate.  If I understand what you're suggesting the put() wouldn't hang...it just wouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to create your own `BlockingQueue` implementation that wraps your old queue and the new queue - poll from the old queue until it's empty, then set it to null to prevent any memory leaks.  This way you won't lose any pending `put`s on the old queue

```
MyBlockingQueue {
  private MyBlockingQueue oldQueue
  private ArrayBlockingQueue newQueue

  ArrayBlockingQueue(int newCapacity, MyBlockingQueue _oldQueue) {
    oldQueue = _oldQueue
    newQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(newCapacity)
    E oldVal = null
    while(newQueue.remainingCapacity() > 0 && 
         (oldVal = oldPoll) != null)
      newQueue.put(oldVal)
  }

  boolean isEmpty() {
    (oldQueue == null || oldQueue.isEmpty) && newQueue.isEmpty 
  }

  void put(E e) {
    newQueue.put(e)
  }

  E take() {
    E oldVal = oldPoll
    if(oldVal != null) oldVal else newQueue.take
  }

  E poll() {
    E oldVal = oldPoll
    if(oldVal != null) oldVal else newQueue.poll
  }

  private E oldPoll() {
    // If you have more than one consumer thread, then use a temporary variable
    // for oldQueue - otherwise it might be set to null between the null check
    // and the call to poll
    if(oldQueue == null) null
    else {
      E oldVal = oldQueue.poll
      if(oldVal != null) oldVal
      else {
        oldQueue = null
        null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean. A nice big pseudo code explanation.  Thanks for the time Zim-Zam!  (I don't know why Slashdot's notifier sent 16 messages about your response to my inbox...maybe it was just very excited about it?)

Answer (score 1):

To your questions:

1) There isn't one that allows you to manually change the queue size, although something like a LinkedBlockingQueue will *grow* up to the max that you set for it.

2 and 3) You could do what you described (create a new ArrayBlockingQueue) using the 3rd constructor described in the docs:

**ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity, boolean fair, Collection c)**

*Creates an ArrayBlockingQueue with the given (fixed) capacity, the specified access policy and **initially containing the elements of the given collection**, added in traversal order of the collection's iterator.*

This gives you the copy construction that you're looking for, and allows you to set the new capacity.  Sizing up:

```
// create the first queue
Queue smallQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(5);

// copy small queue over to big queue
Queue bigQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10, false, smallQueue);
```

Sizing down (pseudocode):

```
Queue bigQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
// start processing data with your producer / consumer.

// then...
Queue smallQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(1);
// 1) change producer to start doing puts into the smallQueue
// 2) let consumer continue consuming from the bigQueue until it is empty
// 3) change consumer to start polling from the smallQueue
```

Your puts from step 1 will block until you switch the consumer over.

Comment: Now /that's/ interesting.  That allows me to grow the maximum size of the buffering....

Comment: Forgot hitting <return> submits the comment.  *sigh*  As I was saying, that allows me to increase the buffer...but what about for reducing it?  If my user decides to turn the buffering off (reduce down to 1 item in the queue), what I'd like to happen is that any put()s are blocked, the queue empties as normal, and when the capacity is down to the desired level, I could then copy it across, and finally complete the put() calls.

Comment: Hrm...that identifies the problem...I don't see a way to see if there are any put() calls pending, or a way to shift them to the new Queue.  Ouch.

Comment: This is off the top of my head, but I'd create a new queue, size 1, and point your producer and consumer to it.  Nothing will go into the old queue now but it might not be empty.  Make one call of drainTo() on the old queue, then you should be good.  Edit: I see the issue, yeah if you're potentially backed up with blocked puts you'd need to poll until the queue is empty.